# Image Tracking and Object Placement with 2 buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

Hey everyone I am new to this AR Foundation, I am trying to build an app which is when launched shows 2 buttons, Button 1 names as "Solar System' and button 2 as "Image Tracking", so what i am trying to achieve is when the user clicks button 1 , he can place an object in the real world using the plane detection, and if the user clicks the 2nd button, user can place an image to detect and and the prefab appears on it.

what I did is, I have attached plane detection and image ARTrackedImageManager with 2 empty objects and both objects are the child of AR Session, and i have added a script called Objectivator, so when the button 1 clicks, the ARsession and child 1 with plane detection is enabled and child 2 with ARTrackedImageManager is disabled and vice versa for button 2.

Is this correct way or am I missing something?

Expert Advise Please.
Thank You